# How do you delete a page in Notability for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

How do you delete a page within a note in (specifically) Notability for iPhone? This information seems to be missing in the app's Help documentation.

Comment: I have had notability for a while and you only had to slide the note to the left on the list of notes view to delete it On recent updates that delete option is no longer available I sure hope they add the slide to the left delete option again in future updates Greetings from Mexico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I asked Ginger labs and they said:

> Yes, you are correct. You can only delete pages on iPad and Mac. We see how adding this to iPhone would be helpful. We'll add this to the list of possibilities for the future. Thanks for your feedback!

On the iPad, if you click on the top right icon (the one that looks like pages, not the paintbrush one), you'll see a bunch of thumbnails. (My screenshot is from the Mac app, but the layout is similar.) This is the "page navigator icon".

[image]

Now you should see red "x" circles on different pages. Tap those and you can delete a particular page.

[Ginger Labs Support: Can I Insert, Delete, or Clear a Page?](http://support.gingerlabs.com/customer/portal/articles/273945-can-i-insert-delete-or-clear-a-page-)

Comment: I don't see a "page navigator" icon on the iPhone version.

Comment: @Henrik Good point. I haven't used the iPhone version. I just installed it and I only see the Page Navigator on the iPad and Mac versions. I'd suggest contacting Ginger labs to see if this is possible on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. I'll follow your advice and contact them.

Comment: @Henrik I did - the update is above, that the iPhone app doesn't have the feature. Of course if you want it, it's definitely a good idea to let them know.

Comment: If you appreciate my answer, please consider up voting. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for checking up with Ginger Labs. I did so as well earlier today and got the exact same reply. Credit to Ginger Labs for responding quickly, although I wish they'd acknowledge that such a key feature is in their list of top priorities. Nevertheless, it's a great app and I'm sure they'll fix this not too far in the future.